# Div changing position (jumping?) when animated with jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-animate

Could someone please help me solve this. I've looked all over and most of the answers say to change the overflow to hidden that doesn't seem to be working.

When hovering over the `.nav-not-active` elements, for some reason the `.nav-active`and the div below both get pushed down or seem to be jumping in some way.

Cheers, any help is appreciated.

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dbuzzin/kkr1L5kx/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed the following in the fiddle and it got rid of the jumpiness:

- add `height: 40px;` to navbar-wrapper
- add `overflow: hidden` to the css itself instead of in the js
- remove the `.css` stuff entirely from the javascript and kept only the animation

[updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kkr1L5kx/1/)

Comment: Cheers :) ffs I tried that before but I'd only added the overflow to the .nav-not-active